# What Haskell type system magic allows for the definition of join?

Tags: haskell

The `join` utility function is defined as:

```
join :: (Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a
join x = x >>= id
```

Given that the type of `>>=` is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` and `id` is `a -> a`, how can that function also be typed as `a -> m b` as it must be in the definition above?  What are `m` and `b` in this case?

Comment: What happens if `a` is `m b`, as `id` forces it to be ? This should answer your question.

Comment: This flavor of magic is often called "unification" :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `a`s in the types for `>>=` and `id` aren't necessarily the same `a`s, so let's restate the types like this:

```
(>>=)    :: Monad m => m a     -> (a -> m b) -> m b
id       ::                        c -> c
```

So we can conclude that `c` *is* the same as `a` after all, at least when `id` is the second argument to `>>=`... and also that `c` is the same as `m b`. So `a` is the same as `m b`. In other words:

```
(>>= id) :: Monad m => m (m b) ->               m b
```

Answer (score 10):

dave4420 hits it, but I think the following remarks might still be useful.

There are rules that you can use to validly "rewrite" a type into another type that's compatible with the original.  These rules involve replacing all occurrences of a type variable with some other type:

- If you have `id :: a -> a`, you can replace `a` with `c` and get `id :: c -> c`.  This latter type can also be rewritten to the original `id :: a -> a`, which means that these two types are equivalent.  As a general rule, if you replace all instances of type variable with another type variable that occurs nowhere in the original, you get an equivalent type.
- You can replace all occurrences of a type variable with a concrete type.  I.e., if you have `id :: a -> a`, you can rewrite that to `id :: Int -> Int`.  The latter however can't be rewritten back to the original, so in this case you're **specializing** the type.
- More generally than the second rule, you can replace all occurrences of a type variable any type, concrete or variable.  So for example, if you have `f :: a -> m b`, you can replace all occurrences of `a` with `m b` and get `f :: m b -> m b`.  Since this one can't be undone either, it's also a specialization.

That last example shows how `id` can be used as the second argument of `>>=`.  So the answer to your question is that we can rewrite and derive types as follows:

```
1. (>>=)    :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b        (premise)
2. id       :: a -> a                          (premise)
3. (>>=)    :: m (m b) -> (m b -> m b) -> m b  (replace a with m b in #1)
4. id       :: m b -> m b                      (replace a with m b in #2)
   .
   .
   .
n. (>>= id) :: m (m b) -> m b                  (indirectly from #3 and #4)
```